# How was the world game market segmented in 2011?

Tags: marketing

Is there a source (or perhaps several) presenting how was the world game market segmented in 2011 (or does anybody know themselves)? For example:

- How many casual gamers there are? What is the total business, of which how much in virtual item sales?
- How many console gamers there are? How much is spent in hardware, how much in software?
- How many mobile gamers there are? How much is spent in hardware, how much in software?

And how all above is in different regions / countries?

Comment: I am aware that the questions can be made much more refined and detailed, e.g. on social gamers there is this research

http://www.infosolutionsgroup.com/pdfs/2011_Kabam_ISG_Social_Games_Research_Results.pdf

but I am looking for an overview. Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you hope to gain by having this information?

Comment: What is a "casual gamer"? How do you define that term?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about industry trivia.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you need to pay for this information, and I don't believe the comprehensive information you are specifically asking for is available all from a single source.

There was a [similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15015/casual-games-market-share-distribution) awhile ago asking specifically about casual gaming breakdown. Of the sources provided in that question, the following are likely the most relevant to your broader question:

- [The NPD's Game Industry Reports](https://www.npd.com/wps/portal/npd/us/industryexpertise/videogames/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3g3b1NTS98QY0N_01AjA08PS3ePIEsDIwNLE30v_aj0nPwkoMpwkF6zeJPgkABTT0tjA3d3L2cDT6MQQ8eQ4GBDCzdziLwBDuBooO_nkZ-bql-QHRxk4aioCAAWAr0i/dl3/d3/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS9ZQnZ3LzZfRks1NTlNVDMxR1IwNzBJVUE5R01BMTM2TTM!/?WCM_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=)
- [Video Game Market Research Reports](http://www.marketresearch.com/Consumer-Goods-c1596/Consumer-Goods-Retailing-c80/Video-Games-c774/)

These can provide you breakdowns of the relative distributions of (sometimes potential) casual or console gamers based on retail metrics and whatnot. I believe they both are US-focused, however. You'd have to find similar organizations for other regions.

Obtaining accurate financial statistics (total revenue in the casual space, et cetera) is not practical because not all companies disclose this information.

Comment: irrelevant comment: when I read your first sentence, I immediately imagined some villain screaming "You will PAY FOR THIS!"

Comment: All of my answers should be read in Evil Villain Voice.

Comment: http://www.explosm.net/db/files/Comics/Dave/comicsuperheroes1.png